# Visual studio community 2017 standalone compiler

Tags: visual-studio

I need to just install visual studio 2017 community edition compiler and build tools for pure C++ standalone development and not their IDE etc. Where can I get their package . The standalone installer of visual studio community 2017 – 15.5.3 
https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15&page=inlineinstall shows me the following screen [image] . This is too much size and I do not get what should I select and deselect to get a basic c++ programming setup done . 
By basic i mean c++ programs to create command line utilities like hello world program and small dlls ; i do not plan to create windowing applications.

Comment: How "basic" are you talking about? You'll need to be specific about what you mean by that. Do you plan to use MFC or ATL, for example? Or do you need the Test Adapter for Google Test? If not, you can uncheck those. Perhaps you can uncheck the profiling tools. I don't think you can avoid installing the IDE, however, even though they do provide command line tools.

Comment: @lurker . updated . By basic i mean c++ programs to create command line utilities like hello world program and small dlls ; i do not plan to create windowing applications

Comment: The IDE can still be used even for writing console applications and DLLs, and is very helpful in that regard (with the context menus and other programmer helpers). You could do everything with an ASCII editor and the command line tools, but the IDE core is part of Visual Studio and I don't think you can just install the command line tools only.